# Variable number of image buttons

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

basically what am doing is am querying some data from firebase and inside these data is a URL for an image of a specific item. Now since its a query i could get different result form the firebase where i can get 4 images or sometime maybe 1 image.
And i want to display the images in a grid layout ( similar to that of Instagram posts) where the user can click on an image and it shows the user some details about that item. This is the part where am stuck at.. i dont know how to do it since i have a variable number of images.

if there is a way, please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Recyclerview and provide the model with those details. It will automatically create those many rows in list.
Here you can follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) to do this.